# How to concatenate a field in a form with a var in Twig?

Tags: twig, concatenation, symfony4

I'm trying to work with a loop in a Controller (in Symfony4) to create a form, with different lines

```
for ($i=1 ; $i<=$nblig ; $i++)
                {
                $formBuilder  ->add('date'.$i, DateType::class)
                              -> (...)
                }
```

The form works fine (I can dump it).
I need a similar loop, when I try to render that form with Twig :

```
{% for i in 1..nblig %}
  {{ form_widget(form.date ~ i)) }}{% endfor %}
```

And I don't know how to concatenate the field name *date*, with the var *i*.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are now combining the value of `form.date` with `i`, what you want, you can use either the array notation or use `attribute` for

```
{{ form_widget(form['date' ~ i]) }}
```

---

```
{{ form_widget(attribute(form, 'date'~i)) }}
```